# How to obtain specific value of choice box in JavaFX

Tags: mysql, sql, javafx, fxml

I have a test database `employees` and a table `employee_db` 
I want to obtain all **employees in a list**, what I have managed somehow to do and the list shows the  `employees`. Now what I need is that when I choose employee on that list, that his `name, age, address, salary` show up in a text field

```
public class employeeController {

@FXML
private TextField name;
@FXML
private TextField age;
@FXML
private TextField address;
@FXML
private TextField salary;
@FXML
private TextField delete;
@FXML
private TextField selUp;
@FXML
private Button updateBtn;
@FXML
private ToggleButton eId;
@FXML
private ToggleButton eName;
@FXML
private ToggleButton select;
@FXML
private ToggleButton update;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox employeeList;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox updateList;
@FXML
private TextArea infoArea;
@FXML
private TextField newValue;

List<Employees> emp_collection;
ResultSet rs;
ObservableList<String> empCol = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("ID", "Name", "Age", "Address", "Salary");
Employees emp;

public employeeController() {

}


@FXML
private void update() throws SQLException {


  if(!update.isSelected()){
      updateList.setVisible(false);
      updateBtn.setVisible(false);

  }
  else if(update.isSelected()){
      updateList.setVisible(true);
      updateBtn.setVisible(true);
       try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees", "root", "ljubisa97");) {
        Employees emp = null;
        emp_collection = new ArrayList();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employees.employee_db where emp_id = 3;");
        ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {

            emp = new Employees(rs.getInt("emp_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getString("address"), rs.getInt("salary"));


            updateList.getItems().add(emp);

        }



    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
  }










public class Employees {

private int id;
private String name;
private int age;
private String address;
private int salary;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Employees() {

}

public Employees(String name, int age, String address, int salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public Employees(int id, String name, int age, String address, int salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + getId() + " Name: " + getName() + " Age: " + getAge() + " Address: " + getAddress() + " Salary: " + getSalary() + "KM\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}
```

}

Comment: What are `updateList` and `updateBtn`? They are not declared in the code you posted (and, in the case of `updateList` at least, are pretty much fundamental to the question). Why are you only adding the string representation (`toString`) of the employee to the list, instead of adding the `Employee` instance itself?

Comment: @James_D Added code

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Your edit changed what you add to the choice box: now you have a different entry for *each field* in the `Employee` object? Why on earth are you doing that? Don't use raw types (your IDE should be warning you about that). Instead, use a `ChoiceBox<Employee>`, and just do `updateList.getItems().add(emp)`. Then the code posted in the answer should work for you.

Comment: @James_D Sorry , it was a wrong code, actually tried that  and it only gets me first entry in DB , figured out  it is letting  me use Employee methods, so all I had to do is use ChoiceBox<Employee> . Sorry I am completely new to Java and first time trying to do programming, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the `value` property of the `ChoiceBox`:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    updateList.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        boolean disable;
        if (newValue == null) {
            disable = true;
            name.setText("");
            ...
        } else {
            disable = false;
            name.setText(newValue.getName());
            ...
        }
        name.setDisable(disable);
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't have a getName() method for newValue, so I can only obtain full string , name, age , address and etc

Comment: So the question isn't about a `ChoiceBox` of Employeeses (`ChoiceBox<Employees>`)???